# Apache multiple DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver, httpd.conf, document-root

How can I have the following setup in apache?

`http://server/ABC/*`    should be served by       `/var/www/ABC/*`

`http://server/PQR/*`    should be served by `/var/www/PQR/*`

*Every other request* should be served by   `/var/www/Others/index.php`   (a single file).

Thanks,

JP

Comment: For the first part of your question: [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) (`Alias /ABC /var/www/ABC` etc.) Leaving the DocumentRoot as /var/www/Others/

Answer (score 27):

Use Alias:

```
Alias /ABC/ /var/www/ABC/
Alias /PQR/ /var/www/PQR/
```

Leave the document root pointing to /var/www/Others/index.php. It could do the trick. :)

Comment: Can this be used to point the `/` to another directory? e.g. `Alias / /var/www/wordpress/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with mod_alias, which is part of the apache distribution.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

for serving everything else with the single file you would use mod_rewrite. This has many features and depending on your needs you might need to tweak that.. but something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

you would put that in a .htaccess file in the document root.

Comment: Pointing document root to index.php, but gives warnings when restarting apache, but *works*. I am thinking whether to use mod_rewrite or Tabers suggestion.