# Configure Apache .conf for Alias

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

So I cant get an alias working in "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf" which contains all
of my virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *> 
    ServerName example.com
    Alias /ncn /var/www/html/ncn
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mjp
</VirtualHost>
```

I want my alias to work so I can point example.com/ncn to "/var/www/html/ncn".

This works if I have it in "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" but not my "/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf"

Any ideas why? Everything else seems to work i.e. ServerAlias's

Cheers, Peter

Comment: Closed? Sure that makes sense, because no programmer ever has to touch a webserver right? </sarcasm> How about all of the rest of the "non-programming" questions, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538572/apache-multiple-documentroot)?  *Pedant!*

Comment: Yeah, looks like this should have been posted in serverfault.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This worked in the end:

```
<VirtualHost *> 
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mjp

    Alias /ncn "/var/www/html/ncn"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/ncn">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So the important option is including all the directives within the VirtualHost directory.

Comment: update __2016__: use this inside <Directory> for recent versions of apache: `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Require all granted`

Comment: What happens when ``/var/www/html/ncn`` is outside the root directory, let's say ``ncn`` is inside ``/home/username/``, owned by ``username:username``, obviously ``www-data`` doesn't have access to ``ncn`` now, and say, we don't want to change the ownership of the directory but still give ``www-data`` user access to ``/home/username/ncn``, how do we do that?

Comment: I created a symlink from my local folder into the /var/www/ folder and was able to access those files.
sudo ln -s /media/$USER/Extra/<abc> /var/www/<xyz>
And then create an "Alias" to /var/www/<xyz> as mentioned above.

Comment: @Flion The answer is regarding a conf file. How to achieve it through htaccess file?