# Create drupal alias to a 2nd instance

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I have a single server with two instances of drupal (6 & 7) running on this server. One instance is my root domain mysite.com, the other instance (d7) is on a sub-domain, video.mysite.com. Rather than use a subdomain we want to do something like mysite.com/videos. Is there a way to create a URL alias that points to this 2nd instance of drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias in your apache conf. Maybe you could use this example as a base: [Configure Apache .conf for Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770778/configure-apache-conf-for-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You will have to remove the entry for the subdomain "**video.mysite.com**" from the DNS. Place the D7 version of the website in a folder "video" within the root directory of D6. Give all the permissions for the video folder & you can access it using mysite.com/videos